# Is there a way to update feature's style in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have some markers colored according to some numbers in a database. Periodically my script performs a query asking for my numbers. If some conditions are met, I want my markers to change colors e.g. from green to yellow.

A similar problem was the radius of these markers that when zooming the map should have increased. I solved this problem by updating the radius in a listener that wakes up when I change the zoom.

```
var currZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
    var newZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
    if (currZoom != newZoom) {
        console.log('zoom end, new zoom: ' + newZoom);
        currZoom = newZoom;
        vectorSource.clear();
        var greenStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: Math.pow(33,newZoom/5)/15000,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)'}),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'green', width: 1})
            })
         });
         var yellowStyle = new ol.style.Style({
             image: new ol.style.Circle({
                 radius: Math.pow(33,newZoom/5)/15000,
                 fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.5)'}),
                 stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                     color: 'yellow', width: 1})
              })
          });
         var redStyle = new ol.style.Style({
             image: new ol.style.Circle({
                 radius: Math.pow(33,newZoom/5)/15000,
                 fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'}),
                 stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                     color: 'red', width: 1})
              })
          });

         for(var i=0;i<Features.length;i++){
             var oldcolor = Features[i]["g"]["e"]["a"]["a"];
             if(oldcolor=="green" || oldcolor=="yellow" || oldcolor=="red"){
                 if(oldcolor=="green"){
                     Features[i].setStyle(greenStyle);
                 }
                 else if(oldcolor=="yellow"){
                     Features[i].setStyle(yellowStyle);
                 }
                 else{
                     Features[i].setStyle(redStyle);
                  }
              }
          }
          vectorSource.addFeatures(Features);
     }
});
```

And this works. When I zoom the radius change its value and the circles change dimensions.

The problem is in this function that it is called when those conditions I mentioned happen.

```
                    function stampaMappa(r){
                        vectorSource.clear();
                        /*for(var j=0;j<Features.length;j++){
                            Features.pop();
                        }*/
                        Features = [];

                        for(var i=0;i<r.length;i++){

                            var id = r[i]["Sensor_id"];
                            var people = r[i]["tot"];
                            var index_color = r[i]["color"];
                            var sniffer_name = r[i]["Sniffer_name"];
                            var lon = parseFloat(r[i]["Sensor_longitude"]);
                            var lat = parseFloat(r[i]["Sensor_latitude"]);

                            var d = new Date();
                            var h = d.getHours();
                            var m = d.getMinutes();
                            var hrs = h+":"+m;

                            var areaFeature = new ol.Feature({
                                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
                                  name: sniffer_name,
                                    tourists: people,
                                    hour: hrs
                            });
                            var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
                                 geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
                                  name: sniffer_name,
                                    tourists: people,
                                    hour: hrs
                            });

                            iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
                            areaFeature.setStyle(colors[index_color])

                            Features.push(areaFeature);
                            Features.push(iconFeature);


                        }
                        if(first_time){
                            vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                                features: Features //add an array of features
                            });

                            vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                                name:"test",
                                source: vectorSource
                            });

                            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
                            // Set the view for the map
                            map.setView(view);

                        }
                        else{
                            vectorSource.addFeatures(Features);
                        }
                    }
```

I expected this to work but it only deletes my markers. They appear again if I zoom in or out (because the zoom listener works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use style functions instead of styles.  The function is called whenever the map renders (which happens for every change of resolution)

```
    var greenStyle = function(feature, resolution) {
      return new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: Math.pow(33,map.getView().getZoom()/5)/15000,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)'}),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'green', width: 1})
        })
      });
    }
```

It's more memory efficient to define the basic style once outside the function and set the radius for each call

```
    var greenBase = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 1,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)'}),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'green', width: 1})
        })
      });

    var greenStyle = function(feature, resolution) {
      greenBase.getImage().setRadius(Math.pow(33,map.getView().getZoom()/5)/15000);
      return greenBase;
    }
```